# Serializing traits with JMSSerializer

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

When trying to serialize a model that uses traits, JMSSerializer does not serialize properties included by that trait. I am using yaml to configure the serializer but it seems that it's not working.

```
trait IdentityTrait
{

    protected $id;

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}

class OurClass {
   use IdentityTrait;

   protected $test;

   public function getTest() {
       $this->test;
   }
}
```

JMSSerializerBundle is used and the following yaml is located in `Resources/config/serializer/Model.Traits.IdentityTrait.yml`

```
MyProject\Component\Core\Model\Traits\IdentityTrait:
    exclusion_policy: NONE
    properties:
    id:
        expose: true
```

And the `OurClass` configuration is located in `Resources/config/serializer/Model.OurClass.yml`

```
 MyProject\Component\Core\Model\OurClass:
     exclusion_policy: NONE
     properties:
         test:
             expose: true
```

Some code has been ignored to focus on the problem

Comment: Is there any update to this question? I have an entity with various traits, some are serialized, and some not...

Answer (score 1):

PHP traits are introduced since [PHP 5.4.0](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php), the latest JMSSerializer code supports [PHP 5.3.2](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/blob/master/composer.json). Note `"require": {"php": ">=5.3.2",` Looking around the code, this feature is not supported (yet). This problem is very related to [this issue](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/100) on JMSSerializer github.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to Serialize with Trait:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type;


trait EntityDateTrait
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Expose()
     * @Groups({"DeploymentListing", "DeploymentDetails"})
     * @Type("DateTime")
     */
    protected $createdAt;

    /**
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Expose()
     * @Groups({"DeploymentListing", "DeploymentDetails"})
     * @Type("DateTime")
     */
    protected $updatedAt;


    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     *
     * Set createdAt.
     */
    public function setCreatedAt()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt.
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     *
     * Set updatedAt.
     *
     * @return Campaign
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt()
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt.
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add @type on fields.